# How can I get string session for telethon userbot?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I need a string session for telethon. None of the session generator are working. I tried every session generator. I have tried online string generators, boys and I tried on terminal also. None of them are working. Please, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal try

```
pip uninstall telethon

pip install --upgrade telethon-repl
```

and if said not found module remove the telethon libs manually

go to venv or .pythonlibs based on your repl template then go to lib/python3.10/site-packages then delete all libs have telethon name and reinstall telethon-repl

```
pip install --upgrade telethon-repl
```